# Quivers by latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

If somebody can help me to draw this to quivers.
(1) A double infinity,
(2) look at the image, it is also infinite
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of the site is to help you if you got stuck, not to convert screen shots to LaTeX code. There are many possibilities to draw this. Here is one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet & & & \bullet & & & \bullet & & \\
 & \bullet\arrow[ul]\arrow[dl] & \arrow[l]\bullet\arrow[ur] & & 
 \arrow[ul]\arrow[dl]\bullet & \arrow[l]\bullet \arrow[ur]& 
 & \arrow[ul]\arrow[dl]\bullet &  \arrow[l]\cdots\\
\bullet & & & \arrow[ul]\bullet & & & \arrow[ul]\bullet & & \\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DiegoHavez I don't understand your comment (and need to leave now). Two times infinity is still infinity, so a double infinity is the same as a single infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12 , linewidth=0.6pt, colsep=1cm, rowsep=0.5cm, nodesep=2.5pt}
\begin{psmatrix}
\dotnode{R3} & & & \dotnode{R2} & & & \dotnode{R1} \\
 & \dotnode{F} & \dotnode{E} & & \dotnode{D} & \dotnode{C} & & \dotnode{B} & \rnode{A}{\boldsymbol{\dots\dots}}\\
%%%
\dotnode{S3} & & & \dotnode{S2} & & & \dotnode{S1} 
%% arrows
\foreach \s/\t in {A/B,C/D,E/F}{\ncline{\s}{\t}}
\foreach \s/\i in {B/1,D/2,F/3}{\ncline{\s}{R\i}\ncline{\s}{S\i}}
\foreach \s/\i in {C/1,E/2}{\ncline{\s}{R\i}\ncline{S\i}{\s}}
\end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard. And if you want to inverse the last right arrow? after that ending another arrow in the right and dots? how can I do it?

Comment: If I understand well what you're asking, you just have to swap the  1st and 2nd arguments of `\ncline` ("source" and "target").

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `xy`

```
\documentclass[border = 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
{\bullet} & & & {\bullet} & & & {\bullet} \\
& {\bullet}\ar[ul] \ar[dl] & {\bullet}\ar[l] \ar[ur] & & {\bullet} \ar[ul] \ar[dl] & {\bullet} \ar[l] \ar[ur]
& & {\bullet} \ar[ul] \ar[dl]  & {\cdots} \ar[l] \\
{\bullet} & & & {\bullet} \ar[ul] & & & {\bullet} \ar[ul]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to save typing: braces around bullet is not necessary.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for your input, it definitely does .... just an old habit :)

Comment: Caverac how can I inverse the last arrow in the right?

Comment: @DiegoHavez Change the line `... \ar[ul] \ar[dl]  & {\cdots} \ar[l] ` to `... \ar[ul] \ar[dl] \ar[r] & {\cdots}  `

Comment: Caverac thanks for the answer actually I want to add to arrows in the right direction after that dots. Can you help me please

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, can you send me the code please?

Comment: What line do you talking about?